# Regular Expression to get "left" only from style

Tags: regex

This is my regular expression to get "left" and its value.

```
/(left\s*:\s*)(\d+)?(px)/
```

My problem is, it pulls padding-left and left.

```
vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; display: list-item; width: 420px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 700px; height: 580px;
```

How can I get "left" and its value only?

I put a \s in front of left and that works... But I can't always guarantee there will be a space in front of left.

Thanks...

Comment: which language/tool are you using..also if its javascript why not interact with DOM itself. `document.getElementsById(id).style.left;`

Comment: why do you want to capture "left"? It's a constant - you already know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(?:^|[^-])(left)\s*:\s*(\d+|auto)([a-z]{2})?/
```

Will fetch what you want with "left" in group 1, "700" in group 2 and "px" in group 3

`(?:^|[^-])` = The start of the string, or a non-hyphen character

`(left)` = The word left  (capture group 1)

`\s*:\s*` = A colon with optional space characters either side

`(\d+|auto)` = One or more numbers, or the string "auto" (capture group 2)

`([a-z]{2})?` = Two letters, e.g. "px" "em" "pt" (capture group 3 - optional)

Comment: SmokeyPHP That Rocks! However I ran into a problem that sometimes there is "auto" for a value instead of "0"... How can I get auto or d+

Example:  vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; display: list-item; width: 700px; position: absolute; top: auto; left: auto; height: 1220px;

Comment: @no1uknow See the update - simply turn `(\d+)` into an 'or' statement with a pipe `|` character, so it's now `(\d+|auto)`

Comment: @no1uknow This update will however match "left: autopx;" - I've left this as a possibility as I can't see it being an issue, and it will slightly increase the complexity of the expression (and lower the readability), but I can certainly remove that possibility if needed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a RegEx, you could use a CSS parser. This is a more robust solution as a parser is better suited for this task.

## An example using Python and [cssutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssutils/)

### example.css

```
.myClass {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 100px;
    left: 700px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

### get-left.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cssutils
sheet = cssutils.parseFile('example.css')

for rule in sheet:
    if rule.type == rule.STYLE_RULE:
        for prop in rule.style:
            if prop.name == 'left':
                print("{0}: {1}".format(prop.name, prop.value))
```

In this Python script, `prop.name` will return the name of the property and `prop.value` its value.

### output

```
$ ./get-left.py 
left: 700px
```